# GKE Ingress - Managed Cert multiple services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to provision some https routes to a GKE instance for a number of services. There are obviously many ways to do this, I'd prefer to stay GCP native where possible.

Using GKE native resources can I achieve something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: tools-managed-cert-toola
  namespace: toola
spec:
  domains:
    - tools.acme-uat.com
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: tools-managed-cert-toolb
  namespace: toolb
spec:
  domains:
    - tools.acme-uat.com
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: toola-ingress
  namespace: toola
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "acme-tools-ip"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: plumbing-managed-cert-toola
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "tools.acme-uat.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/toola"
        backend:
          service:
            name: toola-server
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: toolb-ingress
  namespace: toolb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "acme-tools-ip"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: plumbing-managed-cert-toolb
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "tools.acme-uat.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/toolb"
        backend:
          service:
            name: toolb-server
            port:
              number: 80
```

This feels like the wrong direction though. Is it more conventional to switch the services on the GKE instance to `NodePort` and provision an upstream HTTPS LoadBalancer to manage the routing and TLS termination? This would obviously require scripting, so a GKE native approach is preferred if there is a way?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you are trying to achieve here. You want to deploy two apps (toola and toolb) on GKE and expose them behind tools.acme-uat.com/toola and tools.acme-uat.com/toolb accordinaly ?
Do you care if tools.acme-uat.com points to the same IP's and certificate ?

Comment: Yes. I would prefer to use 1 ip an cert.  It feels clunky this way though as I have two certs for the same IP in different namespaces. My gut feel approach here was to use an edge proxy to manage the path based routing but Id prefer to stay GKE native. So, the question is, is the above a standard approach?

Comment: Aha, i get it now, your apps are in different namespaces.

So Kubernetes Ingress is namespace bound, you cannot reference a backend in a different namespace than the Ingress.

Unfortuanly the issue you will have is that you cannot use the same domain for two different ManagedCertificates. The domain (tools.acme-uat.com) has to resolve to the IP address of the Ingress for ManagedCertificates to work. You will have to use two domains, maybe toola.tools.acme-uat.com and toolb.tools.acme-uat.com

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, what i would recommand you to do is look at the Gateway API, the nextGen Ingress API in GKE https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api

Comment: I've been following that in the k8s space. Looking forward to it going GA. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes soon it will go GA. Meanwhile i'm a co-maintainer of this repo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-recipes. We try to document use cases similar to your's. Feel free to have a look around and if something is missing open an issue, i will be happy to take a look

Comment: Gateway API is the best solution, but in the short term if you want to share the same certificate, you can generate a Google Managed Certificate with multiple SANs directly using the API and then reference the same certificate in multiple ingresses using the `networking.gke.io/pre-shared-certs` annotation.

Comment: A second solution is to create an HTTP Load Balancer directly via the GCE API and configure the certificate for it.  For your GKE services, you can create a standalone NEG for each ( https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#how_to ) and then configure those NEGs as backends for the LB you created ( https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#attaching_a_load_balancer_to_your_standalone_negs ).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @boredabdel, you can't cross namespaces like that. This has also been discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89917).
And you can find some workarounds in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739513/google-kubernetes-engine-how-to-define-one-ingress-for-multiple-namespaces).